# 8 Candidate Buzzer Circuit

Tags: latch, piezo-buzzer

[image: Buzzer Circuit]
I am designing the following circuit for my college quiz club.
I have replaced the bulbs `BL1` to `BL8` with suitable LEDs and resistors.
Now, the issue here is that given a 5V input (from a USB hub), the logic works fine, but the LEDs are very weakly lit and the buzzer doesn't produce any sound.  If I power it via a 9V battery, all the LEDs glow brightly and the switches `S1` to `S8` don't have any effect.
To fix this, I was thinking that the buzzer and the LEDs would need their separate power supply to be activated by some transistor based switch.
Is there any way that can be avoided?

Edit:
Here is the [website](http://electronicsforu.com/electronicsforu/circuitarchives/view_article.asp?sno=212&article_type=1&id=864&tt=unhot) I got the circuit from.

Comment: Your LEDs glow bright an switches don't work because the [74LS373](http://www.uni-kl.de/elektronik-lager/417819) has a max supply voltage of 5.5v, so 9v is a 'bit' overkill.

Comment: In that case, @RSM how can I fix this? 
The [website](http://electronicsforu.com/electronicsforu/circuitarchives/view_article.asp?sno=212&article_type=1&id=864&tt=unhot) is quite unclear on the input power supply to be used.

Comment: What resistor do you have in series with the LED? Lower the value of the resistance to get the LEDs to shine brighter.

Comment: @geometrikal been there, done that. :)
I've even tried them without any resistors, for that matter. Same result. Very feeble light from the LEDs, but the logic worked just fine.

Comment: The website is very clear that a 5V supply is required and includes the schematic for one.

Comment: @Barry the schematic shows a 7.5V 500mA power supply. Am I right? In any case, it also says to use 6V bulbs. How does that work out?

Comment: The power supply is a 7.5 volt AC transformer, and if you read a little further you will see that "regulated 5 volts" is described. Also, immediately after Schematic 2, it says "One terminal of push-to-on switches S1 through S8 is connected to +5V", which is the output of the 7805. Finally, driving a 6 volt bulb with 5 volts works just fine, except that the bulbs are not quite as bright as they would be with 6 volts.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast that is exactly what I was confused about. I tried with a 7.5V wall-wart, a 9V battery and a 5V input from USB hub. Only the 5V "regulated" input gave me desired logic output but with the feeble light.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a small regulator such as an LM78L05 to supply all but the lamps and the buzzer. One part plus a couple small capacitors. You could use a 9V or 12V supply at the input for lots of noise and brightness (but make sure you stay within acceptable limits for current and voltage on the LEDs and piezo transducer). I suggest a small regulated wall plug adapter.

Presumably there's something else (not shown) to reset the SCRs because otherwise they will stay on until the power is cycled.

You may have damaged the 74L373 with 9V, that's well above its absolute maximum supply voltage of 7V.

Edit: See below. \$\mu\$A78xx is [LM78M05](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/LM/LM78M05.pdf) or LM78L05 or LM7805 (TO-220 will run cooler)

[image]

Comment: The 74LS373 is working fine with an input of 5V. So the IC doesn't seem to be damaged.
A circuit diagram would be very helpful, to elucidate your point.

Comment: I will try to do it later- appropriate tools are not available here.

Comment: @spehro - the website the OP linked says that the switch `S9` must be toggled to reset the whole thing from the latch state

Comment: @RSM  Okay, didn't see that in the question. Ah, that's because it's in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: @RSM I did that as well. S9 is just the main power supply switch.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I didn't want to comment before trying out your circuit.  
Two issues come to light now:  
+ The output at the `A` terminal of SRCx and GND seems to be only around 2.25V. Technically, that should drop to 0V to allow my bulb to glow at full brightness, right?

Comment: No, not 0V. The drop across an SCR (when 'on') is typically a volt or so depending on type and current. See the datasheet for your SCR type.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Okay, so in that case, how would my bulb/LED light up? I have say 9V on the cathode and 1V on the anode, correct?

Comment: 9V on the top of the lamp, ~1V on the bottom -> 8V for the lamp. The SCR (when on) has 1V on the anode and 0V on the cathode (the latter is grounded so it is 0V by definition).

Comment: That is what I thought as well. The issue is, I am never getting more than ~2.8V across my LED. The circuit has been precisely followed. What can be the issue?

Comment: Okay, @SpehroPefhany, I got the buzzer working for two switches, but the issue still remains that the output across my LEDs is just not going above ~1.5V. Are my SCRs damaged?

Comment: What is the series resistor value? What are the voltages?

Comment: No LEDs connected. Just testing with a voltmeter. When button is pressed, buzzer starts buzzing and voltage across `A` of `SCR1` and the 9V power rail shows 1.65V.
Again, on resetting, it goes back to 0V.

Comment: So you're using the SCR to short out the power supply? That does not sound very productive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22043/discussion-between-kanishka-ganguly-and-spehro-pefhany).

Comment: Sorry, I'm doing a bunch of other things. Chat is too time consuming.

Comment: I had connected the LEDs earlier to check out the circuit. Buzzer was making a noise and I could see a VERY faint light on the LEDs. So, I checked the voltage across the two terminals of the LED with multimeter, it was 1.65V. 
On resetting with `S9`, it went back to 0V. 

Basically, the logic is working fine. Corresponding LEDs are lighting up on button press and buzzer is sounding. But the LED brightness concerns me.

Answer (score 0):

If you've tried powering your circuit from 9 volts, you have likely fried the 74LS373 and may well have damaged the LEDs.  It's possible for even a seriously-damaged LED to kinda-sorta work, so you may not really know what you've got to work with until you start over with some new components.

A silicon-controlled rectifier will have a significant voltage drop, and is really not the best kind of thing to be using to drive your LEDs.  I would suggest that some other circuit topology might work better.

One that might be cute would be to use a 555 timer to generate a 200Hz or so signal and feed that into a CP0 input of a 74HC4017 decade counter chip (e.g. http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/74HC4017D,653/568-8146-2-ND/1230369).  Feed the outputs of the counter to the LEDs with a common current-limiting resistor.  Also tie each output to one side of a switch through a conventional diode (the positive side toward the ouptut).  The other side of all the switches should be tied in common to the /CE, which should have a weak (47K or so) pull-down.

When no button is pushed, all the lights will strobe at about 20Hz.  Pushing a button will cause the strobing to stop at the corresponding light until the button is released.